# Using ajax on webpage loaded from disk in WPF WebBrowser - CORS blocked

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, wpf

I am using AJAX via XMLHttpRequest on webpage loaded from disk in WPF WebBrowser. XMLHttpRequest.onerror handler is called every time and url is correct so I guess the request is blocked by disabled CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing. I have an idea serving the local page by means of PHP and set header Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Can the problem be solved another way, please?

Comment: Can you post the exact exception you are getting?

Comment: No exception is thrown at all. Only `XMLHttpRequest.onerror` handler is called and the parameter is empty.